# I keep on getting this error, can't find what I'm doing wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, bots

This is the code line for that error:

```
if msg.startswith("!del"):
   encouragements = []
  if "encouragements" in db.keys():
    index = int(msg.split("!del",1)[1])
    delete_encouragement(index)
    encouragements = db["encouragements"]
  await message.channel.send(encouragements)
```

And this is the error I keep on receiving:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
        await coro(*args, **kwargs)
      File "main.py", line 69, in on_message
        index = int(msg.split("!del", 1)[1])
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'm getting the error every time I try to run the !del command.

Comment: Can you fix the indentation of the code sample to match *exactly* the code that you are using?

Answer (score 1):

The exception "IndexError: list index out of range" could happening when the msg is split but the result only contains one element. The code is trying to fetch the second element but only one element exists. See the examples below:

```
msg="!del"
print('one',msg.split("!del",1))

msg="something"
print('two',msg.split("!del",1))

msg="something"
print('three', msg.split("!del",1)[1])
```

Output:

```
one ['', '']
two ['something']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-4193103020d6> in <module>
      6 
      7 msg="something"
----> 8 print('three',msg.split("!del",1)[1])
      9 
     10 

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a basic python error. Kindly  check out docs on [split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and sequence's index.

If you're using [`discord.Client`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#client) object for your bot, you'll probably want to take a look at [`commands.Bot`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#bot) object.